# Unable to convert SQL query to Entity Framework Core

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I am unable to convert my SQL query to Entity Framework Core.

The SQL query is:

```
select * 
from tests 
join TestParameters on (tests.Id = TestParameters.TestId) 
join PatientTests on (Tests.Id = PatientTests.TestId) 
where PatientId = 3
```

The models are shown here:

```
public class Tests
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Test Name")]
    public string TestName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Short Name")]
    public string  ShortName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name="Technical Name")]
    public string  TechName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name ="Test Price")]
    public float TestPrice { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Sub Department")]
    public int SubDeptId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Center")]
    public int CenterId { get; set; }

    public string Separate { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Sub Department")]
    [ForeignKey("SubDeptId")]
    //relation of departments table
    public virtual SubDepartments subDepartments { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Centers")]
    [ForeignKey("CenterId")]
    //relation of departments table
    public virtual Centers centers  { get; set; }
}

public class TestParameter
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Categories { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Test Parameter Name")]
    public string ParameterName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Unit { get; set; }

    [Display(Name ="Decimal Point")]
    public int DecimalPoint { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Help Value")]
    public string HelpValue { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Normal Range")]
    public string NormalRange { get; set; }

    public string Minimum { get; set; }

    public string Maximum { get; set; }

    [Display(Name="Test Footer")]
    public string TestFooter { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Tests Name")]
    public int TestId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("TestId")]
    //relation of departments table
    public virtual Tests Tests { get; set; }
}

public class PatientTest
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Display(Name ="Patient Id")]
    public int PatientId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name ="Test Id")]
    public int TestId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name ="Doctor")]
    public int DoctorId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name="Center")]
    public int CenterId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Test")]
    [ForeignKey("TestId")]
    //relation of Tests table
    public virtual Tests Tests { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Doctor Reference")]
    [ForeignKey("DoctorId")]
    //relation of Doctors table
    public virtual Doctors Doctors { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Center Reference")]
    [ForeignKey("CenterId")]
    //relation of Centers table
    public virtual Centers Centers { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Patient")]
    [ForeignKey("PatientId")]
    //relation of Patient table
    public virtual Patient Patient { get; set; }
}
```

`PatientTests` contains relations of patient, tests, testparameters.

I tried to convert it but it's returning single data.

My code is:

```
var test = await _db.TestParameters
                    .Include(p => p.Tests)
                    .Where(p => p.Tests.Id == pttp.patient.Id)
                    .ToListAsync();
```

Comment: When you are using Navigation Property (As you do not correctly implement it), You don't need to check to join parameter. So `.Where(p=>p.Tests.pttp.patient.Id==3)`.
I strongly recommended reading this tutorial: https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/one-to-many-conventions-entity-framework-core.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might split the query into two queries.

1) Select patient tests

```
var patientTests = _db.PatientTests
    .Include(x => x.Test)
    .Where(x => x.PatientId == pttp.parient.Id)
    .ToList();
```

2) Select parameters of the tests

```
var testIds = patientTests.Select(x => x.TestId).ToList();
var testParameters = _db.TestParameters
    .Where(x => testIds.Contains(x.TestId))
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Thank u Mr. Martin
I need one more help i want to re-arange it with parent child relation
tests is parent and TestParameter is child of tests
Like
Test1
  TestPara1
  TestPara2
  TestPara3
Test2
  TestPara1
  TestPara2
  TestPara3